# What is wrong with what I made using signs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft I had a fast clock and two command blocks:

```
 #1 execute @p[score_Lot1_min=0] ~ ~ ~ setblock -6 6 1 wall_sign 2 replace {Text1:"Lot 1", Text3:"$15,000"}

 #2 execute @p[score_Lot1_min=1] ~ ~ ~ setblock -6 6 1 wall_sign 2 replace {Text1:"Lot Tooken"}
```

No matter what my Lot1 score is it always uses the first command, but it says it works on both command blocks. Any Help

Comment: I think you want "Lot Taken"

Answer (score 1):

The first one is probably being executed after the second, and since your score is at least 0, it executes, overriding the other. I think you have to use `[score_Lot1_min=0, score_Lot1=0]` to check exact value.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is executing both commands at the same time, it will pick the one that applies the most, in this case the first command block.  This is because even if your `Lot1` score is greater than one, the first command where your `Lot1` score only needs to be greater than zero.

Because of this both commands are being executed but, the first one is true in every situation making it apply further.

Comment: Commands are never executed at the exact same time. In this case, the first one is likely executed after the second. I also suggest adding fixed commands to your answer.